# Why does my API call not return when everything is synchronous?

Tags: rest, promise, async-await, frontend, backend

I have a Vue.js application on the frontend and a Node.js REST API on the backend (on AWS).

I was making a call to the backend from the front end and getting a 504 error (gateway timeout) and I couldn't figure out why. Then I copied the code from an almost identical pattern elsewhere in the application and it worked. I don't know why it worked. I'm hoping that someone can explain to me why my code didn't work and why the code I copied does work.

First you need to know what my code looks like. So here it is:

FRONTEND:

```
     async saveTimestamp() {
       try {
         await api.post(`blahBlahEndpoint`);
         this.flag = false;
       } catch (err) {
         console.log('err=', err);
       }
     }
```

BACKEND:

RequestHandler:

```
require('./blahBlahController').setSomething(params);
return new HttpResponse(204);
```

Controller:

```
setSomething(params) {
  this.dao.setSomething(params);
}
```

DAO:

```
setSomething(params) {
  this.db.runQuery('blah blah query with params');
}
```

So essentially, the front end sends a post request to the backend. The endpoint is our RequestHandler, and once it figures out the right controller and method for the job, it requires the controller and calls the method, passing it any parameters that came with the request. The controller in turn calls a method on the DAO passing the parameters along. The method on the DAO (setSomething(...)) injects the parameters into a query string which gets passed to db.runQuery(...). db.runQuery is from a third party library. It essentially runs the query against our database (in my case, doing a simple field update). It's asynchronous and therefore returns a promise. As you can see, I'm ignoring the promise and just returning right away (I don't need the results of the query so I just let it do its thing and carry on). So other than runQuery(...), everything is synchronous. Why then does my frontend call timeout? After about a minute of waiting, the catch block catches a 504 error, which google tells me is a timeout error.

Now let's look at the fix:

FRONTEND:

```
     async saveTimestamp() {
       try {
         await api.post(`blahBlahEndpoint`);
         this.flag = false;
       } catch (err) {
         console.log('err=', err);
       }
     }
```

BACKEND:

RequestHandler:

```
await require('./blahBlahController').setSomething(params);
return new HttpResponse(204);
```

Controller:

```
async setSomething(params) {
  await this.dao.setSomething(params);
}
```

DAO:

```
async setSomething(params) {
  await this.db.runQuery('blah blah query with params');
}
```

Very simple. I just converted everything on the backend to async/await. But why does this fix the problem. I'm obviously not understanding how the async/await pattern handles promises and/or how that changes the dynamic between frontend and backend (at least with REST APIs).

Here's some assumptions I'm making that may be false:

1) Without the async/await pattern (where the bug existed), all method calls from the RequestHandler to the DAO only return when the method is done, and they return nothing (with the exception of the RequestHandler which returns a HttpResponse with a 204 status to the front end).

2) Because runQuery is asynchronous, it returns a promise, and it returns it immediately (i.e. before it is done).

3) Since DAO.setSomething(...) does not await the call to runQuery, it carries on as soon as it's done calling runQuery. The promise returned from runQuery is dropped. While runQuery does its thing (updating the DB), the API begins the return portion of its round trip, returning nothing.

4) RequestHandler finally returns an HttpResponse object to the frontend. At the frontend, this object becomes the object of the Promise being awaited, effectively resolving the promise and permitting the API call to stop awaiting.

^ 4) is what doesn't seem to happen. All backend logs indicate that everything works just as I describe above, right up to the point of returning the HttpResponse, and the updates to the database corroborate this. This tells me there is an issue with how my code above (pre-fix) effects the way by which the backend returns to the frontend, but what exactly?

Here's what I imagine is happening with the fix:

1) No changes to frontend. Frontend makes call to backend like before.

2) In RequestHandler, call to setSomething(...) in controller is made asynchronously, which means it returns a promise right away and is awaited.

3) In Controller's setSomething(...), call to DAO.setSomething(...) is made. Since this is asynchronous, it returns a promise right away and is awaited.

4) In DAO.setSomething(...), call to runQuery(...) is made. Since runQuery(...) is asynchronous, it returns a promise right away and is awaited.

5) Once the promise returned from runQuery(...) is resolved (because runQuery(...) finishes), DAO.setSomething(...) returns.

6) The promise returned from DAO.setSomething(...) is resolved by DAO.setSomething(...) returning, and it stops awaiting. This causes Controller.setSomething(...) to return.

7) The promise returned from Controller.setSomething(...) is resolved by Controller.setSomething(...) returning, and RequestHandler stops awaiting.

8) RequestHandler returns the HttpResponse object to the frontend with status 204.

9) The promise returned from the api call is resolved by way of the HttpResponse object being returned. The promise resolves into the HttpResponse object. The frontend stop awaiting and continues on.

^ Hopefully, this gives a detailed account of what my understanding is surrounding frontend requests and backend responses, and what happens when promises and async/await patterns are involved. Does anyone care to correct any misunderstandings I have? Anything that would explain why the frontend wasn't getting a response in the pre-fix state?

Thanks very much for any forthcoming responses.

Comment: Can't follow the server code with so much code missing and no real arguments and no real operations included.  It's too much psuedo code.  For example, we can't see any actual real asynchronous operations to know what does and doesn't return a promise.  ANYTHING that returns a promise, you have to either use `.then()` or `await` on it unless you don't care when it ends or if it has an error, which is a very rare circumstance so nearly all of the time, you have to use `.then()` or `await` on a promise.

Comment: FYI, things returning promises are apparently not synchronous (they are probably asynchronous if they're using promises) so perhaps the assumption in the title of your question is just wrong.

Comment: This is probably true, but then my question is: what DOES happen when you don't await or add .then to an asynchronous function? Take the call to Controller.setSomething in RequestHandler for example. It's asynchronous and therefore returns a promise right away (i.e. before it completes), but in the pre-fix code, I don't await or .then it. Does it not just continue right after it's called, and return HttpResponse to the frontend?

Comment: Asynchronous operations that nobody is listening for the completion of will continue to run and return their value (via a promise) to nothing.  Unless it actually has the response object (which has the http connection in it) and can literally send the response itself, then there won't be any code receiving its return value and thus no response gets sent.  That's where all the missing code hides us from seeing what is really happening here.